# How to compile this on Windows

Tags: c++, gcc

Ok. I am trying to compile the following application on Windows ([Segmenter](http://www.ioncannon.net/programming/452/iphone-http-streaming-with-ffmpeg-and-an-open-source-segmenter/), see step 3).

I checked out the source and changed the references so that'd all be good. It's basically a one file app, with a reference to ffmpeg.

The `makefile` reads:

> gcc -Wall -g segmenter.c -o segmenter -lavformat -lavcodec -lavutil -lbz2 -lm -lz -lfaac -lmp3lame -lx264 -lfaad

I have the Visual C++ compiler, but I just have no clue how to compile the above line using that compiler, or should I grab [Gcc for Windows](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gcw/)?

Comment: yes, grab gcc. You can choose from either MingW or Cygwin

Comment: IMO, compiling an open source app falls into SuperUser's land.

Comment: There are thousands of questions regarding the use of gcc and related tools on SO - I've never seen a single one moved to SU.

Comment: @Neil: Definitely. "How do I reference these libraries" is completely a SO question but compiling an app that comes with a README file indicating how to compile is basically an installation thing. Indeed this is a gray area. Not a big issue anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line indicates a very simple compile.  It's compiling the file with one standard argument (-g for compiling with debug symbols, on MSVC it's /Zi).

But it's linking with a lot of libraries (that's all the -l options).  I recognize two of those as standard compression libraries (bz2 and z), so you are going to need to build those libraries first.

Answer (score 2):

Don't consider using cygwin unless the project you are working on absolutely requires it. Download the MinGW version of GCC plus binutils like make from http://tdragon.net/recentgcc. I've never heard of the version of GCCyou provide  a link to in your question - MinGW is the mainstream project in this area.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have source for the libraries you are linking in, you'll probably have to use the compiler that compiled them.

Answer (score 1):

```
cl -c -W4 segmenter.c -Fosegmenter.obj
link segmenter.obj avformat avcodec avutil bz2 faac mp3lame x264 faad
```

I'm not sure that to do with -lm and -lz though.
In fact, all of these librarys will need to be built by the MSVC compiler for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to [use cl.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235639%28VS.80%29.aspx) that you already have. You can use [/Wall](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thxezb7y%28VS.71%29.aspx) instead of -Wall . (W controls how warnings are generated.)

R Samuel Klatchko gives the rest of what you should need to know.